# Open file based on user input

Tags: c++, file-io, command-line

I want to get the input file name in advance, when my program is called, not have my program ask the user for the filename.

I've seen many examples where the program will ask the user for input like:

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Enter file name: ";
    cin.get();
    //run program
    return 0;
}
```

However, there are not many examples shown where the input is stated in the command line when the program is called:

```
int main(int argv, char* argc[])
{
    ifstream inputfile;
    inputfile.open(argc);
    //run program
    return 0;
}
```

In other words, the user would type something like this on the terminal:

> $./program example.txt

Sorry if my question is like an ELI5 submission.

I think you guys might get the gist of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 ifstream inputfile;
 if(argc == 2)
  inputfile.open(argv[1]);
 else
  cout<<"Please nenter filename as command line argument!\n";
 //run program
 return 0;
}
```

Here, `argc` and `argv` are called **command line arguments**.

The value of `argc` is equal to the number of command line arguments, which includes the filename of the executable file itself.

`argv` is an array of strings passed as command line arguments, where the name of the executable file is at `argv[0]` and the rest of the arguments follow that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
inputfile.open(argv[1]);
```

However, I suggest adding checks to the program.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if ( argc < 2 )
    {
       cerr << "Not enough arguments.\n";
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // There is an argument. Use it.
    ifstream inputfile;
    inputfile.open(argv[1]);

    //run program
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int main(int argv, char* argc[])` should be `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`.

Comment: @AhmedAkhtar, thanks for pointing out the error. It's fixed now.

Comment: Yeah I feel dumb because I already had checks to exit the program but I didn't understand the way program inputs were done. Thanks.

Comment: @DeadSupra, you'd better grow some thick skin if you want to continue programming. Things like this will happen a lot :)